Can I make the closet opening larger on my own?
This small closet by my front door could look nicer. We found a bifold door that looks great but it turns out it needs a rough opening of 82” but the closet is only 80”, and the door can’t be cut shorter. I know the closet can be opened up and the header raised, but I’ve never done this before and it’s a load bearing wall.


Is this something I could realistically do on my own or do I need a professional?
It’s definitely a load bearing wall, and the new door is 2” taller than what I currently have.

Changing load bearing walls does call for professional advice at least.

Are you sure that is a load bearing wall?  If not, then then possibly of the house falling down is much less and the problem is not making too much of a mess/have the final job look half way decent.  Outside walls and usually the centre wall will be load bearing.  Most of the other walls are there to hold up drywall.

Most bifold doors start with an 82" rough opening that I am aware of. It is needed to fit the track in over the door, and the door is sized smaller as well to fit under the track. If the door has a finished jamb overhead of a certain thickness, typically 3/4", if needed, because you new to you door is taller than the original, perhaps the 3/4" head piece can be replaced with thinner material. There is a chance the original jamb may need to be redone anyway.

Please take the [tour]. Resolutions don't belong in questions, and if you don't intend to accept or provide an answer you should delete the question.

82 inches is the rough opening requirement.  You probably have that now as it is a standard for any 80 inch door.
Your pictures show a bifold door currently in the opening. The new door very well may be a direct fit.  Check the size of the actual new door and what the *finished opening * size is. Don't worry about the rough opening.  There is no reason to get into load bearing walls and such.
